# Onfacebook logout event

Tags: java, android, ios, facebook, sharedpreferences

is there a method to check when user clicks logout button, i have this to login in my android app :

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
     callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,

 new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
     @Override public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

 // App code
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successful" + loginResult.getAccessToken().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
   loginResult.getAccessToken(),
     new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
             public void onCompleted(
              JSONObject object,
              GraphResponse response) {
               // Application code
       //textView.setText(response.toString());
   JSONObject j_user = response.getJSONObject();
 try {
             KEY_ID = object.getString("id");
              KEY_EMAIL = object.getString("email");
             KEY_NAME = object.getString("name");

           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               }
     Log.i("stringazzo", response.toString());
     Log.i("STRING", object.toString());
    //  Log.i("string", KEY_EMAIL);
     //  Log.i("string", KEY_ID);
     //  Log.i("string", KEY_NAME);
    //   Log.i("SHAREDPREFS",KEY_NAME);
   // Log.i("SHAREDPREFS",KEY_EMAIL);
    editor.putString("name", KEY_NAME);
    editor.putString("email", KEY_EMAIL);
    editor.putString("id", KEY_ID);
     editor.commit();
                                          System.out.println(editor.commit());
  }
});
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
request.setParameters(parameters);
 request.executeAsync();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login error"+exception.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

when user logins in my app i get some datas from Facebook and i save them in SharedPreferences and when user is logged the login button became logout, i want that when user clicks the logout button all my SharedPreferences will be set with "0" values.

and in my iphone app too

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

the facebook login and logout button are the same, and fired the same events when clicked. So what you have to do is, verify if users are logged or not.

Like this:

```
Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken(); //manually force profile fetching from current token
    if(Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null) { //if it available
        Log.d("TAG", "LOGGED ");
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "Profile is null UNLOGGED");
    }
```

I hope it helps. ;)